# Assigning a state property to a constant in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, constants, assign

I'm currently going through the React JS tutorial, and I keep seeing this kind of thing, where some property of the state is assigned to a constant before usage :

```
render() {
  const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
  return (
    <div>
      L’utilisateur <b>{isLoggedIn ? 'est actuellement' : 'n’est pas'}</b> connecté.
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is there something I'm missing there ? This constant assignment looks like a commodity not to overload the JSX, but I'm just not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People do that to make their code cleaner and less repetitive.

```
render() {
  const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
  return (
    <div>
      L’utilisateur <b>{isLoggedIn ? 'est actuellement' : 'n’est pas'}</b> 
connecté.
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is easier to read than:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      L’utilisateur <b>{this.state.isLoggedIn ? 'est actuellement' : 'n’est pas'}</b> 
connecté.
    </div>
  );
}
```

And is noticeably DRYer when you have to use isLoggedIn several times.

```
    render() {
      const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
      return (
        <div>
          L’utilisateur <b>{isLoggedIn ? 'est actuellement' : 'n’est pas'}</b> 
          Hello <b>{isLoggedIn ? 'darkness my old friend' : 'just kidding' }</b> 
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Additionally you will also see object destructuring alot, which creates even less code:

```
render() {
  const {isLoggedIn} = this.state;
  return (
    <div>
      L’utilisateur <b>{isLoggedIn ? 'est actuellement' : 'n’est pas'}</b> 
connecté.
    </div>
  );
}
```

These three examples are identical and have no real functional differences. It's preference if anything.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know yet about the destructuring syntax !

Comment: @OddBrew you're welcome! It's still relatively new in JavaScript. I think you'll like it a lot as you work more with React :)

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Really liked the way of explanation. Came here to answer this question but couldn't find anything that i could add to your answer. Great job.

Answer (score 1):

It's just convention. If you did this too many times, your code would be quite hard to read. It's also easier to debug if you break things up.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
       L'utilisateur <b>{this.state.loggedIn ? "est actuellement" : "n'est pas"}</b> connecté.
    </div>
  )
}
```